# <option> is unclickable, yet it works outside of <aside>

Tags: html, css, menu, html-select

I'm trying to create a drop down list using select and option, the usual. However, it won't work. I've tried everything.

But if I move it to the footer, it works! What in the code is stopping the drop down list from working inside the `<aside>`?

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Intrepid</title>
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<header>
<img src="Images/banner2.png">
</header>
<nav><div class='ribbon'>
<a href='#'><span>Home</span></a>
<a href='#'><span>Destinations</span></a>
<a href='#'><span>Holidays Packages</span></a>
<a href='#'><span>Make a Booking</span></a>
</div>
</nav>
<body>
<content>
<div id="container"><img src="Images/picturebanner.png" height="360" width="980"    alt="Paris">
<aside>

<select>
<option value="volvo" selected="selected">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</aside>


<section>
    <img src="Images/photo-icon.png"><p>blashasakdsakjfdhsakfj djbfsdj sdhjfbsdjkfbs sdhjfbsdsn j h hcjh bhj  h  h db jh j </p>

</section>
<section>
    <img src="Images/photo-icon.png"><p>blashasakdsakjfdhsakfj djbfsdj sdhjfbsdjkfbs sdhjfbsdsn j h hcjh bhj  h  h db jh j </p>

</section>
<section>
    <img src="Images/photo-icon.png"><p>blashasakdsakjfdhsakfj djbfsdj sdhjfbsdjkfbs sdhjfbsdsn j h hcjh bhj  h  h db jh j </p>

</section>

</div>
</content>  

<footer>


</footer>

</body>

</html>






            @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Tinos|Quattrocento+Sans|Text+Me+One);
            
            body{
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            header{
                width: 980px;
                margin:0 auto;
                position:relative;
                }
                
            nav{
                width:920px;
                text-align:right;
                position:relative;  
                top:-170px;
                z-index:10;
                margin:0 auto;
                
                
            }
            nav ul li{
                display:inline;
                margin:0 auto;
                padding:30px;
                font-size:20px;
                
                
            }
            
            
            #container{
                margin:0 auto;
                width:980px;
                position:relative;
                top:-130px;
                z-index:-1;
            
            }
            
            content{
                width:980px;
                margin:0 auto;
                background-color:black;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            aside{
                width:750px;
                height:75px;
                position:relative;  
                top:-150px;
                float:right;
                background-color:#eba600;
                padding:5px;
                
            }
            
            section{
                width:200px;
                padding:55px;
                float:left;
                text-align:left;
            }
            
            footer{
                background-color:#241e20;
                width:980px;
                height:250px;
                overflow:hidden;
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            
            .ribbon:after, .ribbon:before {
                margin-top:0.5em;
                content: "";
                float:right;
                border:1.5em solid #fff;
                opacity:0.7;
                
            }
            
            .ribbon:before {
                border-right-color:transparent;
            }
            
            .ribbon:after {
                border-left-color:transparent;
            }
            
            .ribbon a:link, .ribbon a:visited { 
                color:#000;
                text-decoration:none;
                float:right;
                height:3.5em;
                overflow:hidden;
                
            }
            
            .ribbon span {
                background:#fff;
                opacity:0.7;
                display:inline-block;
                line-height:3em;
                padding:0 1em;
                margin-top:0.5em;
                position:relative;
                margin-right:1.0em
                
            
                -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s, margin-top 0.2s;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
                -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s, margin-top 0.2s;  /* FF4+ */
                -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s, margin-top 0.2s;  /* IE10 */
                -o-transition: background-color 0.2s, margin-top 0.2s;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
                transition: background-color 0.2s, margin-top 0.2s;
            }
            
            .ribbon a:hover span {
                background:#FFD204;
                margin-top:0;
                
            }
            
            .ribbon span:before {
                content: "";
                position:absolute;
                top:3em;
                left:0;
                border-right:0.5em solid #9B8651;
                border-bottom:0.5em solid #fff;
                margin-right:1.0em;
                
            }
            
            .ribbon span:after {
                content: "";
                position:absolute;
                top:3em;
                right:0;
                border-left:0.5em solid #9B8651;
                border-bottom:0.5em solid #fff;
                
            }
```

Comment: looks like your html is invalid - if you're new to it that's not surprising as it takes a while to learn what elements can go where. A very good tool to help you find problems with HTML is the W3C validator service, you can find it here: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Np8u/)

You need to move your `header` to within your `body` tag, additionally your CSS should be placed within `style` tags in your `head` or, ideally, linked to in an external stylesheet.

You then also need to remove `z-index:1` from `#container`, at the moment it is 'overlaying' your content rendering anything below it (such as the select box) unclickable.